# Why redirecting to #show action without passing the :id param work (in rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple question about rails.

I followed a tutorial (from CrashLearner).
In that tutorial we have a simple resource `message` that generates the regular following routes (excerpt from `rake routes`)

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
    messages GET    /messages(.:format)          messages#index
             POST   /messages(.:format)          messages#create
 new_message GET    /messages/new(.:format)      messages#new
edit_message GET    /messages/:id/edit(.:format) messages#edit
     message GET    /messages/:id(.:format)      messages#show
             PATCH  /messages/:id(.:format)      messages#update
             PUT    /messages/:id(.:format)      messages#update
             DELETE /messages/:id(.:format)      messages#destroy
```

As I understand the route to get to the `show` action of this controller is like something `/messages/17`, I mean we have to put the `:id` of that particular message we want to view.

So, if I needed to redirect the user to this message view after he modified it (in the `#update` action) I should use:

```
redirect_to message_path(17)
```

But it turns out that omitting this `:id` actually works great:

```
redirect_to message_path
```

Why and how this last one work ?

Since this works from an action that actually *received* the `:id` param I suppose that the controller keep it in memory and pass it through by default under the hood when it is missing but I would like to understand where this behavior come from ?

I found nothing in the rails documentation.

Here is the github repository of the tutorial, so the exact specific place of the above line is [here in this controller](https://github.com/CrashLearner/ESPN/blob/master/app/controllers/messages_controller.rb#L30).

And I confirm that this works.

There is also a `Comment` resource that is nested from the previous `Message` resource.
As you can see [in that controller on the `update` action](https://github.com/CrashLearner/ESPN/blob/master/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb#L22), after updating a comment (which is nested within a message) the controller redirects to the `message_path` but in that case the `:id` parameter is present through the instance variable `@message` *(and I learned that this works because the object `Message` respond to an `.id` method otherwise it should be `@message.id`)*

I supposed that the reason that why here the `:id` is still passed is because we are in the `Comments` controller and the `:id` of another resource could not be passed under the hood, thus why it is explicitely written.

I don't have another explication..

Can anyone explain me why this works ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this in [Rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb#L153):

> Missing routes keys may be filled in from the current request's
>   parameters (e.g. +:controller+, +:action+, +:id+ and any other
>   parameters that are placed in the path).

So here `:id` exists in the current request `params` and it's used for this route.

Comment: this is craziness!

Comment: Also these (for the path helper) https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L113 > https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L295 > https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L227 > https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83ee043c6834914607849ae9cd3b9eab6b41702c/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/url_for.rb#L33

Comment: So if my undestanding is good.. This meens that some variable (here the `:id`) is actually kept from one request to another...  
I thought that in RESTful HTTP requests the communication should be stateless (without any data being kept and pass from one request to another)  
Although, some exception exists like the `flash` variable that store some flash messages...

Comment: Also.. I take a look to the source code trace (thank you jphager2)..
In the last file (.../metal/url_for.rb) we saw that the params are gathered from the `request` object and the `path_parameters` method..  
But the `request` is not it supposed to be updated with data from the new request ?  In order to store parameter from previous request, this object should actually swap old vs new data elsewhere, no ?

Comment: It's not actually like that, this variable is not kept from one request to another.
In the update action you have "redirect_to message path" . When it's time to execute this code interpreter sees "aha, there is such route, but params[:id] is missing, let's look at current request parameters", it looks and there is a certain value (e.g. 8). So it redirects to /messages/8 (8 is params[:id]). This is one request.
Next request is "/messages/8", it's parsed and matched to MessagesController#show, where params[:id] is 8 (new :id parsed from request, not saved from previous action)

Answer (score 0):

If you define singular resource you will have show action without `:id` param

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

Comment: In the repository you can see that there are plural resources, not singular:
https://github.com/CrashLearner/ESPN/blob/master/config/routes.rb#L3